# Java 2D Walk Animation Not Working?

Tags: java, animation, awt, java-2d

I am currently working on a long term 2D game project. As of now I am stuck with a really annoying bug that is creating this whenever the character walks: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39SMSvqQSEc&feature=youtu.be

Here is my spritesheet:

[image: Sprite Sheet]

And here is the code for the render method:

```
public void render(Screen screen) {
    int xTile = 0;
    int yTile = 28;
    int walkingSpeed = 3;
    int flipTop = (numSteps >> walkingSpeed) & 1;
    int flipBottom = (numSteps >> walkingSpeed) & 1;
    if (movingDir == 1) {
        xTile += 2;
    }
    if (movingDir > 1) {
        flipTop = 0;
        flipBottom = ((numSteps >> 4) & 1);
        if (movingDir == 2) {
            flipTop = 1;
        }
        xTile += 4 + ((numSteps >> 3) & 1) * 2;
    }
    int modifier = scale;
    int xOffset = x - 8;
    int yOffset = y - 11;
    if(isSwimming){
        int waterColor = 0;
        yOffset += 4;
        if(tickCount % 60 < 15){
            yOffset -= 1;
            waterColor = Colors.get(-1, -1, 225, -1);
        }else if(15 <= tickCount % 60 && tickCount % 60 < 30){
            yOffset -= 1;
            waterColor = Colors.get(-1, 225, 115, -1);
        }else if(30 <= tickCount % 60 && tickCount % 60 < 45){
            waterColor = Colors.get(-1, 115, -1, 225);
        }else{
            yOffset -= 1;
            waterColor = Colors.get(-1, 225, 115, -1);
        }
         screen.render(xOffset, yOffset + 3, 0 + 27 * 32, waterColor, 0x00, 1); // Render right half of player/water ripple
        screen.render(xOffset + 8, yOffset + 3, 0 + 27 * 32, waterColor, 0x01, 1); // Render left half of player/water ripple
        }

    screen.render(xOffset + 8 * flipTop, yOffset + 0, xTile + yTile * 32, color, flipTop, scale);
    screen.render(xOffset + 8 - 8 * flipTop, yOffset + 0, xTile + 1 + yTile * 32, color, flipTop, scale);
    if (!isSwimming) {
        screen.render(xOffset + 8 * flipBottom, yOffset + 8, xTile + (yTile + 1) * 32, color, flipBottom, scale);
        screen.render(xOffset + 8 - 8 * flipBottom, yOffset + 8, xTile + 1 + (yTile + 1) * 32, color, flipBottom, scale);
    }

}
```

And the screen class:

```
package ca.fightnight.game.gfx;

public class Screen {

    public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 64;
    public static final int MAP_WIDTH_MASK = MAP_WIDTH - 1;

    public static final byte BIT_MIRROR_X = 0x01;
    public static final byte BIT_MIRROR_Y = 0x01;

    public int[] pixels;

    public int xOffset = 0;
    public int yOffset = 0;

    public int width;
    public int height;

    public SpriteSheet sheet;

    public Screen(int width, int height, SpriteSheet sheet) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.sheet = sheet;

        pixels = new int[width * height];
    }

    public void render(int xPos, int yPos, int tile, int color, int mirrorDir, int scale) {

        xPos -= xOffset;
        yPos -= yOffset;

        boolean mirrorX = (mirrorDir & BIT_MIRROR_X) > 0;
        boolean mirrorY = (mirrorDir & BIT_MIRROR_Y) > 0;
        int scaleMap = scale - 1;
        int xTile = tile % 32;
        int yTile = tile / 32;
        int tileOffset = (xTile << 3) + (yTile << 3) * sheet.width;
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            int ySheet = y;
            if (mirrorY) 
                ySheet = 7 - y;

            int yPixel = y + yPos + (y * scaleMap) - ((scaleMap << 3) / 2);

            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                int xSheet = x;
                if (mirrorX) 
                    xSheet = 7 - x;
                int xPixel = x + xPos + (x * scaleMap) - ((scaleMap << 3) /2 );
                int col = (color >> (sheet.pixels[xSheet + ySheet * sheet.width + tileOffset] * 8)) & 255;
                if (col < 255){ 
                    for(int yScale = 0; yScale < scale; yScale++){
                        if (yPixel + yScale < 0 || yPixel + yScale >= height) 
                            continue;
                        for(int xScale = 0; xScale < scale; xScale++){
                            if (xPixel + xScale < 0 || xPixel + xScale >= width) 
                                continue;
                            pixels[(xPixel + xScale) + (yPixel + yScale) * width] = col;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }

    public void setOffset(int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        this.xOffset = xOffset;
        this.yOffset = yOffset;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) *"really annoying bug that is creating this whenever the character walks"*  Describe it in words.  I watched the video and am still not sure what you are referring to.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: That is not a bug, that is a gamefeature, FUN looking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all that video made my day. Second why not try using the entire characters body for each sprite so there is no confusion when trying to animate. Create an animation for walking using 2 images in the spritesheet. To walk right have an image of the character facing right with the left foot forward then another for right foot forward then, repeat the process for when walking left.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I got it working :) public static final byte BIT_MIRROR_Y = 0x01; was supposed to be 0x02. Thanks for the help though!